# Search for BTC transactions by amount range

Tags: blockchain

It is possible to search transactions by amount range using blockchain or other website without having hash,  just by range or exact amount?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

[Blockchair.com](https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/outputs) allows for searching by output amount, or transaction total value.